# How to filter by month and year range in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

My document looks like this:

```
{
     id: "abc",
     value: 1234,
     month: 6,
     year: 2018
}
```

How can I filter out the query like the following in aggregation:

```
{
     from: "6/2017",
     to: "8/2018"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it by myself:

```
db.bills.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        {$eq: ["$year", FROMYEAR]},
                        {$eq: ["$year", TOYEAR]},
                        {$gte: ["$month", FROMMONTH},
                        {$lte: ["$month", TOMONTH},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {$eq: ["$year", FROMYEAR]},
                        {$lt: ["$year", TOYEAR]},
                        {$gte: ["$month", FROMMONTH]}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {$gt: ["$year", FROMYEAR]},
                        {$eq: ["$year", TOYEAR]},
                        {$lte: ["$month", TOMONTH]}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {$gt: ["$year", FROMYEAR]},
                        {$lt: ["$year", TOYEAR]}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "id": 1,
        "month": 1,
        "year": 1,
        "_id": 0
    }
},
,
{
    $sort: {
        "year": 1,
        "month": 1
    }
}
]).toArray()
```

The first is to extract fromYear, fromMonth, toYear, toMonth from query. The next is to set it to corresponding position in the query. 
There are 4 ranges to match:

```
MinYear = $year = MaxYear ==========> MinMonth < $month < MaxMonth
MinYear = $year < MaxYear ==========> MinMonth <= $month
MinYear < $year = MaxYear ==========> $month <= MaxMonth
MinYear < $year < MaxYear ==========> any $month
```

The result looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "BI_0010",
        "month" : 5,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    {
        "id" : "BI_0008",
        "month" : 3,
        "year" : 2018
    },
    {
        "id" : "BI_0001",
        "month" : 8,
        "year" : 2018
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this problem i would suggest you to use $lt and $gt filters in mongodb query. For example,I solved the problem with below query:

```
    db.getCollection('Bills').find({"month":{$gte:6, $lte:8},"year":{$gte:2017,$lte:2018}})
```

Use '**gte**' for greater than equal to and '**lte**' for less than equal to. Likewise '**gt**' for greater than and '**lt**' for less than.
The above code worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank for you comment, but your logic is not true. How about 12/2017?