# mongo get data within a month and year range

Tags: mongodb, date, range

I want to get data within a month and year range. My documents are like this

```
 {
    "month": 12,
    "year": 2019,
    "accounts": [
        1094,
        1093,
        1087,
        1081,
        1080
    ]
}

{
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2020,
    "accounts": [
        1094,
        1093,
        1087,
        1081,
        1080
    ]
}
```

I tried the following code

```
$condition = array('year' => array('$gte' => intval($start_year), '$lte' => intval($end_year)), 'month' => array('$gte' => intval($start_month), '$lte' => intval($end_month)));
$pipeline = array(
                    array('$match' => $condition),
                    array('$sort' => array('month' => 1)),
                    array('$project' => $project)
                );
$res = $mlab_con->$collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

But this is not correct.
For Eg

startmonth = 5

startyear = 2019

endmonth = 2

endyear = 2020

Here in month calculation, greater than 5 and less than 2 will return nothing. How can I correct this?

Comment: I think this will work..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609373/how-to-filter-by-month-and-year-range-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        { year: { $gte: 2019 } },
        { month: { $gte: 5 } }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        { year: { $lte: 2020 } },
        { month: { $lte: 2 } }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NJLJtEJDZH-)